# How can I pass POST params through DELETE rest API?

Tags: php, restful-architecture, http-delete

I want to delete many items by it's Ids with DELETE Rest API.

For example: Post Param: Ids: "112,324,323,544"

But In the process function I can't get that Post params.

```
$ids= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ids');
var_dump($ids); exit; ==> return NULL

$ids= $_POST["ids"];
var_dump($ids); exit; ==> return NULL
```

Any suggest to write a Rest Delete API for many ids?

Comment: try using $_REQUEST...

Comment: yes, I tried, but NULL again!

Comment: Try to print whole incoming POST data, may be you're wrong in key names